# SQL difference between two timestamp and categorizing to 1 minute bucket

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on a sample project, where I am using a tool called TDV(TIBCO Data Virtualization) that supports both oracle and Postgres SQL. I have two timestamp columns startDate and endDate with some values, I am trying to expand the data to 1 minute but I am having trouble getting it in the desired format. The difference between the startdate and enddate is not constant, sometimes it is 3 minutes or 5 or 7. I did some research and couldn't find the right solution.

**Sample Data**

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
|     StartDate      |      EndDate       | Val1   |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
| 3/22/2020 10:06:30 | 3/22/2020 10:11:29 |     10 |
| 3/22/2020 14:20:51 | 3/22/2020 14:25:50 |     22 |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
```

**Desired Result**

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
|     StartDate      |      EndDate       |     Time_1Min      | Val1   |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
| 3/22/2020 10:06:30 | 3/22/2020 10:11:29 | 3/22/2020 10:07:00 |     10 |
| 3/22/2020 10:06:30 | 3/22/2020 10:11:29 | 3/22/2020 10:08:00 |     10 |
| 3/22/2020 10:06:30 | 3/22/2020 10:11:29 | 3/22/2020 10:09:00 |     10 |
| 3/22/2020 10:06:30 | 3/22/2020 10:11:29 | 3/22/2020 10:10:00 |     10 |
| 3/22/2020 10:06:30 | 3/22/2020 10:11:29 | 3/22/2020 10:11:00 |     10 |
| 3/22/2020 14:20:51 | 3/22/2020 14:25:50 | 3/22/2020 14:21:00 |     22 |
| 3/22/2020 14:20:51 | 3/22/2020 14:25:50 | 3/22/2020 14:22:00 |     22 |
| 3/22/2020 14:20:51 | 3/22/2020 14:25:50 | 3/22/2020 14:23:00 |     22 |
| 3/22/2020 14:20:51 | 3/22/2020 14:25:50 | 3/22/2020 14:24:00 |     22 |
| 3/22/2020 14:20:51 | 3/22/2020 14:25:50 | 3/22/2020 14:25:00 |     22 |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
```

Comment: I would suggest you tag with one database.  The data resides *somewhere*.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Okay sure, will update, you mean to remove a tag right? Thank you

Comment: @Nik in future posts please do not post images [see why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) use formatted text instead. A good method for formatted text [see here](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/). Copy and paste the results and enclose them in lines containing ```.

Comment: @Belayer Sure, will keep in mind about not posting the image and regarding the tool, its TDV(TIBCO Data Virtualization) I will update the same in the question as well for future reference.

Comment: Why does the date change in the new column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff That was a mistake on the excel sheet, considering Belayer suggestion and have updated the question from image to text

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (startdate, enddate, time_1min, value) as
      select startdate, enddate, trunc(startdate) + interval '1 minute', value
      from t
      union all
      select startdate, enddate, time_1min + interval '1 minute', value
      from cte
      where time_1min < enddate
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, I tried your suggest, had to bit change the syntax. I am seeing time_1min with only date no time and also it is doing a cross join. For example in the desired result I have to see 5 rows but I am seeing more than 500 rows

Comment: @Nik . . . Can you set up a db fiddle?

Comment: Creating DB Fiddle for the 1st time, [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qEfN7hYnjHJAhVwVhZ9c3g/0) let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

You say that you are using a tool that supports both Oracle and Postgres, but you do net let us know what that tool is. There is not much through the tool we can suggest. So I offer a Postgres [solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9e90d6af4108886a9a391b1974836164) based on generate_series instead of a recursive CTE.

```
select startdate, enddate, time_1min, value 
  from t 
 cross join generate_series(date_trunc('minute',startdate)+interval '1 minute)'
                           ,date_trunc('minute',enddate)
                           , interval '1 minute'
                           ) gs(time_1min)
 order by startdate, time_1min;
```